# Customize nested control inside a BasedOn style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, styles

I'm approaching to WPF (in particular I'm working on MVVM) and I'm trying to creating a custom Window style that will be used throughout the application. What I want to do is create a base style that will define the window color, the border, icon, title, etc. The Window can be resizable or dialog like, so I used WindowChrome to set up the "resizable window" that has minimize, maximize and close buttons by default and that's, in fact, resizable. For the Login window I would like to have a window that uses the base style, but the user can't resize or maximize it, so the maximize button should not be visible at all. I've been working on BasedOn styles and I can override properties succesfully, but I can't manage to define which buttons can or can't be visible inside the window. So what I'm trying to do is changing a nested UI control (a `StackPanel` in this case).

Here is the base style I created, that contains, for now, all the window properties and the window buttons as well (I tried to comment it the best I could):

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}" x:Key="DefaultWindowsTemplate">

    <!-- The outer border of the Window -->
    <Border Padding="{Binding OuterMarginSizeThickness, FallbackValue=10}">

        <!-- The inner border of the Window and the Window itself, from the contour line to the shadow -->
        <Grid>
            <Border CornerRadius="{Binding WindowCornerRadius}" 
                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource AlizarinBrush}" 
                    BorderThickness="{Binding OutlineBorderThickness, FallbackValue=1}"
                    Background="{StaticResource VoidnessBrush}">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect Color="{StaticResource Voidness}" ShadowDepth="0" Opacity="1"/>
                </Border.Effect>
            </Border>

            <!-- The Container grid, composed by the title bar and the content area -->
            <Grid>

                <!-- Rows definition -->
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="{Binding TitleHeight, FallbackValue=30}"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <!-- Title bar row that contains icon, title and window buttons -->
                <Grid Margin="{Binding TitleHeightMargin}" 
                      Background="{StaticResource VoidnessBrush}" 
                      Grid.Row="0" 
                      Panel.ZIndex="1"
                      >

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>

                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <!-- Window icon -->
                    <Button Margin="5 5 0 0" 
                            Style="{StaticResource WindowIconButtonStyle}" 
                            Command="{Binding MenuCommand}">

                        <Image Source="/Images/Logos/khm_logo_titlebar.png"/>

                    </Button>

                    <!-- Window title -->
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                               Foreground="{StaticResource ConcreteBrush}"
                               Margin="15 5 0 0"
                               TextAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Title, FallbackValue='Window Title'}"/>

                    <!-- Window buttons - THIS IS THE CONTROL I WANT TO DEFINE INSIDE 'BASED ON' STYLES, WHERE I WILL NOT HAVE THE MAXIMIZE BUTTON -->
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2"
                                Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <Button Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonsStyle}"
                                Content="0"
                                Command="{Binding MinimizeCommand}"/>

                        <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource MaximizeWindowButtonStyle}"
                                      Command="{Binding MaximizeCommand}"/>

                        <Button Style="{StaticResource WindowCloseButtonStyle}"
                                Content="r"
                                Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"/>

                    </StackPanel>

                </Grid>

                <!-- The Window content -->
                <Grid Margin="1 5 0 0" Grid.Row="1">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="Window" x:Key="DefaultWindowsStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource DefaultWindowsTemplate}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{Binding WindowMinWidth}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{Binding WindowMinHeight}"/>
    <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>
</Style>
```

Then I start editing the base style as following (in another XAML file of course):

```
<Style TargetType="Window" x:Key="DialogWindowsStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultWindowsStyle}">
    <!-- REMOVE THE MAXIMIZE BUTTON INSIDE THE NESTED STACK PANEL -->
</Style>
```

So what is the right way to edit part of the UI while using the same style?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: I would define boolean attached properties `local:MyWindow.ShowMaximizeButton` etc. with default values of `true`, then use `TemplateBinding` in the template, and apply them in styles as desired. Can provide example if needed, it's just a pile of boilerplate code mostly.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Unfortunately the concept of attached properties is quite new to me, so an example would be really appreciated. Anyways, that's something I could start looking around for, so thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define boolean attached properties `local:WindowExt.ShowMaximizeButton` etc. with default values of true. In the ControlTemplate I'd apply those to the buttons with TemplateBindings, and set them via style setters (or directly on Window elements in XAML).

Here's an example of `ShowMaximizeButton`; the others are just the same thing with different names. When you copy and paste the dependency property definition, be careful you update the property name every place it appears. I use snippets to create those, to minimize careless errors.

```
public static class WindowExt
{
    public static bool GetShowMaximizeButton(Window obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(ShowMaximizeButtonProperty);
    }

    public static void SetShowMaximizeButton(Window obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ShowMaximizeButtonProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowMaximizeButtonProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ShowMaximizeButton", typeof(bool), typeof(WindowExt),
            new PropertyMetadata(true));
}
```

Make sure this is somewhere prior to where the window control template is defined, in the same resource dictionary:

```
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
```

The maximize button in the window control template. There won't be any change to the control template other than adding these appropriately bound visibility attributes to the buttons. Note the parens in the Binding's Path; those are critical because it's a multi-part identifier for a single property.

```
<ToggleButton 
    Style="{StaticResource MaximizeWindowButtonStyle}"
    Command="{Binding MaximizeCommand}"
    Visibility="{TemplateBinding local:WindowExt.ShowMaximizeButton, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
    />
```

And usage in the window style:

```
<Style TargetType="Window">
    <Setter Property="local:WindowExt.ShowMaximizeButton" Value="True" />
</Style>
```

Note that attached properties are dependency properties of the control itself, nothing to do with any DataContexts or viewmodels.

Comment: I did a quick research on those AttachedProperties and honestly I don't know how I could miss them... This works like a charm and that's exactly the tipe of solution I was looking for (actually I wasted time on style inheritance). Thank you very much!

Comment: @Belfed Glad to help